# Accessing other method variables in java?

Tags: java

```
public class Document1 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     String i = "A";
     eg();
   }

   public static void eg(){
      System.out.println("    " + i);
   }
}
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: Why would expect it to work?

Comment: The variable i is not available to the eg() method because it is not in scope. You should read a little bit more about variables, methods and their scope.

Comment: If you have a bottle of whiskey in your car, can you drink it in your room? No.. Unless you have a `getter` that brings it to you from the car :D

Comment: @MarounMaroun - Best example ever! ;)

Comment: @MarounMaroun That's why you have *two* bottles of whiskey.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [scope](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3)

You get an compiler error in the below method.

```
 public static void eg(){
      System.out.println("    " + i);
   }
```

Because `i`  is local variable to main method. You cannot access in other methods.

What you can do is, pass that variable to where you want.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     String i = "A";
     eg(i);
   }

   public static void eg(String param){
      System.out.println("    " + param);
   }
```

Comment: thank youu, sorry this is a really easy question I'm new to java...and programming in general...

Answer (score 2):

Because `i` only exists in main scope. you have to pass `i` inside `eg` function, like this `eg(String param)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `i` as an argument to method `eg().`

In your code, `i` is a **local variable** in main method. Therefore, it cannot be accessed by your `eg()` method.

Try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     String i = "A";
     eg(i);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what is known as an issue of `scope`. `scope` is the area of code where a variable is visible. For example:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
     // x can only be used inside this loop.
}
```

Another example is if you declare a local variable inside a method:

```
private void doSomething()
{
     String value = "this can only be used inside doSomething()";
}
```

[Here](http://java.about.com/od/s/g/Scope.htm) is a pretty helpful link explaining the concept.

For your issue, you simply declared a variable inside the method. You should make it a parameterized method:

```
public void eg(String i)
{
    // Your code as normal.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `eg()` method is not aware of the variable `i`. Its within the scope of `main()` method only. You need to either pass it to the `eg()` method or make it an instance variable (in this case, a static variable).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String i = "A";
   eg(i);
}

public static void eg(String i){
   System.out.println("    " + i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `String i` from your function `eg()` because it was declared in the scope of `main`.  You can either declare `i` in a global scope by placing `String i` above your main function.  Or pass it as parameter to your function such as:

```
public static void eg(String i){
```

and change the function call to:

```
eg(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of scope.  Your function eg() cannot "see" the variable **i** because it isn't within its view.  If, however, you did as follows:

```
public class Document1 {
    String i = "A";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        eg();
    }

    public static void eg(){
        System.out.println("    " + i);
    }
}
```

Then it would work because now the variables scope is the whole class file and not just the main method.

Answer (score 0):

It's all to do with variable *scope* - "scope" meaning where the variable is accessible.

In your code, `i` is a "local variable", that has scope only within the method it is declared (and in fact only *after* it's declared). That's why the other method can't "see" it.

Parameters to methods are considered local variables too.

The next level up is an *instance* variable, whose scope is all methods, but only within the context of an instance - each instance gets its own copy.

After that you've got *static* variables, whose scope is every instance - there's only one copy per class in which it's defined.

---

To "fix" your code you can:

- pass the variable as a parameter to the `eg()` method
- create a `static` variable, which would be declared outside the method(s)
- because your methods are static an instance variable wouldn't help, but would work if you made your methods instance methods (non-static) and created an instance of your class